# Will the cycle in Korra Book 2 continue? [Spoilers]

Tags: the-legend-of-korra

Now that Unalaq is dead, will the Dark Avatar cycle continue? He died in the same way Wan did, turned to tiny gold buds and disappeared into the wind, so I'm just wandering what you guys think about that.

Comment: Wan didn't turn into tiny old buds. He just spit some gold stuff (presumably Raava?) that vanished into the air.

Answer (score 4):

If you are asking, will he be back in 10,000 years... we may never know.  Though if he was in **Dark Avatar State** we know that would be the end of *Unalaq* (if **DAS** is like the regular **Avatar State** even Unalaq's spirit is gone).  That being said *Vaatu* is a primal force and from what the series specifically tells us he **WILL** be born again within *Raava*.

If you are asking about more appearances: The **Wall Street Journal** from Nov 22, 2013 interviewed series creators *Michael DiMartino* & *Bryan Konietzko* about the show and what would be in store for **“The Legend of Korra Book 3: Change.”**

Here's what was said about the **Dark Avatar**:

---

**A few more questions from Twitter. @thebarkingdog asked “Will we see more of the Dark Avatar?”**

**DiMartino:** Probably not. Korra pretty much defeats him, so.

---

To read the whole article you can ckick [HERE](http://blogs.wsj.com/speakeasy/2013/11/22/the-legend-of-korra-creators-writing-pretty-much-done-for-final-book-in-saga/), but be warned their are spoilers for Season 2 (which just finished) as well as some talk about the upcoming season. If you would not like any details on **Book 3** you may want to give the piece a miss.

I will say that *DiMartino* & *Konietzko* do make the comment in the WSJ article that the **Avatar Universe** is something they feel they will revisit again-and-again in the future. So one-day we may just find out what happens in 10,000 years...

Answer (score 2):

In a prior episode, Unalaq threatened to destroy destroy Jinora's spirit with a dark version of his water-based spirit bending. The big Vaatu-Unalaq thing attempted the same thing on Giant Blue Korra; and then when she rescued that portion of Raava that Jinora (somehow) managed to implant in Vaatu, Korra used that same waterbending technique on Vaatu-Unalaq.

It seems likely that Vaatu has been destroyed entirely,and so has Unalaq. So no, there will be no reincarnation for either of them -- though as Raava described in *Beginnings*, it is entirely possible that Vaatu will regrow within Raava (and therefore within the Avatar).

Answer (score 2):

On Avatar: The Last Airbender, Roku said that the Avatar Cycle would be broken if the Avatar is killed in the Avatar State. Unalaq was killed in some dark avatar state so I think the dark avatar cycle cant continue.

Comment: Can you provide some kind of reference to this, perhaps an actual quote from the episode in question?

Answer (score 2):

Well, because the dark avatar is the opposite of the light avatar, then possibly everything is backwards?  Such as Ravva wants peace, Vaatu wants destruction. The light avatar can bend the four elements because of Wan before the fuse, the dark avatar could only bend one element before the fuse, so the dark avatar may only be able to bend one element. Why am I going on a rant like this?  My point is since things are opposite, then maybe the avatar state can not continue for the dark avatar when he is not in the avatar state?  This is only a theory, but it seems pretty logical. Just me thoughts though.

Comment: The elemental powers come from the Lion Turtles, not Raava or Vaatu. Raava was able to hold onto the powers for Wan, and that collection in one place, along with Raava's spirit itself, started the Avatar Cycle as we know it. There was no reason to suspect that the Dark Avatar would have those abilities, having never met the Lion Turtles.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it will, just like the Avatar cycle did. So, in theory, a Dark Avatar will be born in the Earth Kingdom soon, and will be able to master Water and Earth. By the fourth Dark Avatar, I assume, he/she will be equal to the Avatar. Let's just hope the Dark and Light Avatars never die at the same time, from the same nation. :P

Comment: What makes you think it will be able to master Water and Earth, not less and not more? I don't see anything that would suggest that's how it works.

Comment: I disagree. Avatar Wan (Waan?) mastered all four elements BEFORE fusing with Raava, so his skills at the time were bound to the cycle. The Dark Avatar will probably only be able to bend water, but will also be much more in tune with the spirits than the Light Avatar

Answer (score 1):

Vaatu cannot be destroyed. There are references to "light can't exist without the darkness" throughout the 2nd season. So Vaatu is banished until he can grow strong again and the battle resumes.

Topdown looking at the tree of time and the 2 portals, you can see that it is a Yin/Yang sign. Cosmic balance and all that...

[Yin/Yang sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yin_and_yang)

[image]

[image]

Now, the depiction of Tree of life and the 2 portals in the cartoon

[image]

You can't destroy a part of something without destroying the Whole. One can't exist without the other. So Vaatu can't be dead, otherwise Rava would be dead too! And moving along, if Vaatu can't be killed, that means that the dark avatar cycle can continue, but Korra did banish Vaatu, so it will probably take a long time for a Dark Avatar to resume his/her cycle.

Answer (score 1):

1. The Cycle of the Dark Avatar is over because Unalaq was in the Dark Avatar State(his growing up and becoming a black-red giant) when Korra destroyed him forever.
   If you remember, Azula nearly killed Aang in Avatar State but Katara saved him...If Katara hadn't done this then Aang would have died forever...If Aang's Avatar State kept on he would have become a white-blue giant like the spitting image of Korra when she meditated and found cosmic energy of the universe.
2. The Cycle of the Dark Avatar is over because when Vaatu connected with Unalaq he said, "We are now ONE." When Korra destroyed him the cycle of the Dark Avatar was over.
3. The Cycle of the Dark Avatar is over because to resurrect Vaatu you would need a part of darkness...
   Jinora resurrected Rava With a part of lightness.

Answer (score 1):

Remember the Avatar state (maybe be it the light or dark), is the Avatar's strength and weakness. If killed in the state, then the cycle would be broken and the Avatar will not exist. Well, that's what Avatar Roku said. Then again, Unalaq was in the Dark Avatar state when he was Unvaatu-zilla. So, if he was killed in that state, the cycle would probably be broken. Well, that's all up to Mike DiMartino and Bryan Konietzko.

It makes you wonder though, what would happen to the Avatar 10,000 years into the future when Vaatu emerges out of Raava? Would this Avatar be bipolar?

Answer (score 1):

For there to be peace there must also be a chaos...

If the Avatar of Peace exists then so too will the Avatar of Chaos run amock.

I just hope they dont make the Chaos Avatar a two-dimensional tool like every other villain in Korra. Maybe instead if brute force he/she uses trickery a la Varrik to provoke war.

Answer (score 1):

The Cycle of Dark Avatar is over. Simply because Unalaq was in Dark Avatar State and connection between Vaatu and Unalaq was destroyed. Of course, Vaatu will reborn inside Raava but it will take some time.

Answer (score 1):

Dark Avatar Unalaq was technically in the Avatar State when he died. Killing the Avatar while in the Avatar State (this applies to dark and light) would sever the connection between the human and the Avatar Spirit, thus preventing another Avatar, because a harmonic convergence (or some other surge of energy) would be needed to remerge the spirit to a human. In addition, Killing an Avatar while in the Avatar State would not necessarily destroy the spirt. When Azula destroyed the Avatar Cycle, she did not necessarily destroy raava, she simply severed Aang's connection to her. Korra, however, also destroyed Vaatu with the cleansing technique. In the future, however, the Avatar would cease to continue anyway(for another 70 years, at least) because there would be no source of energy great enough to permanently merge them. In fact, because harmonic convergence supposedly only happens if the portals are open, the only possible way for Raava to merge with someone else and continue the cycle would be to temporarily merge with someone, and open the portals with them, then remerge permanently.

Also, had the Dark Avatar Cycle continued, it would have gone to air, because it would go in reverse, and also, the Dark Avatar would gain all 4 elements once going through the Dark Avatar Cycle once.

Answer (score 1):

Um no. There is no more dark avatar. Korra destroyed him. And even if he were to be renin inside another human host, He would only have water. The reason The Avatar has all four elements is because 10,000 years ago, Wan split Raava and Vaatu, and then to fix his mistake went to different lion turtles to gain the other elements. Wan was a master of all four elements before he fused with Raava, hence why the avatar has all four. So unless whoever the dark avatar may be goes and searches for lion turtles and gets bending from them (which they wouldn't give him) he would soley have water. However, the dark avatar cycle was broken before it began by Korra when she turned Vaatu and Unaloq light and destroyed them. Unalouq is gone forever, and Vaatu is gone for the time being. As Raava told wan though, "he can not destroy light anymore than I can destroy darkness, one can not exist without the other. Even if Vaatu wins in this encounter, light will grow inside him until I spring free from him, the same holds true if I win"  so as korra destroyed Vaatu during the Harmonic Convergence, Raava won that encounter. Eventually, a new Vaatu will spring free from Raava... And the Avatar. But that Vaatu would not be combined with a human as he was with Unaloq. The only way would be if he fused during the next Harmonic Convergence which isn't for another 10,000 years. And to prevent this, the Avatar could easily close one of the spirit portals, which Korra chose to leave open, and reopen it after the harmonic convergence. Because remember if even one of the portals are closed, the harmonic convergence won't happen.

Comment: Usually an answer to a question does not need a huge rant. Can you simplify your answer so it **actually** seems like an answer to a question? Otherwise, this kind of answer is not what this site is looking for. We're not after synopses, just straight answers.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that if you remember, Wan wasn't the one giving the elements, Rava was. So even if the DAS was to continue (which it won't, he was killed in the avatar state, no matter how pretty it was, you have to accept it) the person would be limited solely to the element that they have. And besides, who's to say that the only reason the cycle goes that way is because that was the order Rava obtained it, hence DA not being able to happen. And a future avatar is going to have one hell of an issue with Vatuu when he comes back (maybe since he regrows from Rava, he will to be bound to the avatar, just fruit for thought).

Answer (score 1):

Unalaq was not in the avatar state. He only grea like that because raw a was destroyed temporarily. His power grew and at that point he couldn't possibly be weaker. HE WAS NOT IN THE AVATAR STATE. The technique korra used was what unalaq does when he calms dark spirits. Yes unalaq is dead but he was not in the avatar state in his giant form just like korra wasn't in the avatar state in her giant form. Therefore th dark avatar cycle will continue. I have two theories about this:

1. Because the dark avatar could only bend his natural element the next avatar (earth) will be able to bend earth. Raavaheld the ability to bend the other elements with her as she went from host to host. Vaatu will carry the ability to water bend with him to the next avatar. The next one will be able to bend earth and water; next fire water earth; next air water earth fire; so on and so forth.
2. The same as the last one except because tha avatars are opposites the next dark avatar will not be earth but air. Now that I think about that might be why random airbenders are popping up out of nowhere. That might be why I heard the antagonist of book 3 will be an air bender. My sources are unreliable though so shouldn't get my hopes up. After all he or she would be a baby when book 3 takes place. And if my other theory is correct then I just disproved myself. My other theory being that since the antagonists of books 1 and 2 were water benders the antagonist of book 3 will be one to.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you see either Korra or Unalaq "spirit bend" you always see them going back into the spirit world so possibly when she Spirit Bent Vattu she could have just teleported him back to the spirit world.

I believe that he will be back with rage because twice the avatar sent him back into the spirit world...

Comment: The first part seems quite reasonable but the second part reads more like a fan theory...

Answer (score 0):

We all know that the Avatar cycle ends when the Avatar dies in the Avatar state. Since Unalaq died when in the dark Avatar state, the cycle will not continue. But that doesn't mean Vattu won't be the main enemy in the third book. I think that in the third book either the conflict between humans and spirits will cause Vattu to grow faster or that someone will pull Vattu out of Korra early just like Korra did to Unalaq

Comment: Is this just pure speculation or is there anything to back it up?