# What happened to Vaatu?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

After the events of The Legend of Korra: Light in the Dark, we see that Korra's spirit calms vaatu with the knowledge of Spirit Calming she learned from Unalaq. Therefore where did Vaatu go as in a spirit cannot be destroyed as said by Raava to Avatar Wan. Therefore where did unalaq and Vaatu's fused spirit go physically??

Comment: This might answer some questions [Will the cycle in Korra Book 2 continue?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/45058/will-the-cycle-in-korra-book-2-continue-spoilers/46194#46194)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> where did Vaatu go as in a spirit cannot be destroyed as said by Raava to Avatar Wan.

When Raava was explaining this, I'm pretty sure that she meant that you can't kill either her or Vaatu *forever*. So Vaatu didn't necessarily go anywhere, but rather just died for the time being.

> where did unalaq and Vaatu's fused spirit go physically?

If we stick to the above idea that Vaatu is dead at the moment, so would be Unalaq (they don't go anywhere physically - they're gone at least until their reincarnation).

But if you're wondering whether *Unalaq's* spirit will reincarnate along with Vaatu, we'd have to speculate a bit:

If they were indeed fused as one entity (both are the same now), then it would be logical that in 10.000 years both would return, as one. However, be mindful that the fusion using the Harmonic Convergence isn't as strong as we thought it was, because clearly Korra was not perfectly fused with Raava, who used the exact same method in the past.

---

Basically, there doesn't seem to be any official word regarding Unalaq's or Vaatu's current state.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't think there would be a reincarnation of Vaatu and Unalaq because technically he was in the avatar state when he "died", so the cycle would end there. I think that the reason the next book is called change because now that Vaatu has been assimilated, the worlds balance has been shifted as there is no longer a dark spirit. Which I hope isn't true, because I loved Vaatu, and I was so happy that he fused with Unalaq. Don't get me wrong, I hoped that Korra and Raava would win, I was just as giddy as a schoolgirl when they did the same thing Raava and Wan did. However, I wasn't exactly expecting him to turn into Satan. Nor was I expecting a macro Korra/Vaatu fight.
I have another theory as well that I really hope is not the case, but the reason that the next book is called change is because as it progresses, Korra becomes more and more evil until Vaatu is reborn within her and escapes. That would just suck balls after seeing her gain the power of the universe just to save Raava (and the world but I like to think it was more about Raava.)

Answer (score 1):

I think when vaatu and unalaq fused and they became the dark avatar, same rules applied for them as they applied to light avatar. When korra killed them they were in an avatar form so korra broke the unstarted dark avatar chain there. It doesn't satisfy me however, that korra can kill something that much powerful without raava's aid but I say to myself "Unalaq have never trained with vaatu like wan did and plus they didn't have the experience of hundreds of light avatars had" to justify the end. In fact this end was not bad either offering something fantastic to wait for.

About vaatu's next appearance, I think he will appear somewhere close to next harmonic convergence in somewhere dark in the spirit world. After all we all agree on raava saying neither can destroy each other and she said if one wins the battle defeated will appear next harmonic convergence. She actually said that.

Damn I would love to see a two avatar world. But it would be too depressing for many viewers I think.

Answer (score 0):

In a prior episode, Unalaq threatened to destroy destroy Jinora's spirit with a dark version of his water-based spirit bending. The big Vaatu-Unalaq thing attempted the same thing on Giant Blue Korra; and then when she merged with the portion of Raava that Jinora (somehow) managed to rescue, Korra used that same waterbending technique.

I believe that Vattu has been destroyed. According to Raava in *Beginnings*, this means that he will regrow within Raava (and therefore the Avatar) until he becomes powerful enough to break free, presumably at the next Harmonic Convergence in ten thousand years time. Perhaps this will be an element of future seasons of Korra, or future series in the Avatar franchise. Or perhaps Wan (by merging with Raava) and/or Korra (by doing what she did) have changed things enough that Vattu has finally been destroyed forever. But that second one would seem like a tremendous waste of a potential story to me.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I know vaatu neither exists. 
Vaatu can not be gone. unulaq is a man so he can not leave. The only 
that he has no control forces. And vaatu least possible strength. 
Vaatu Satan. Vaatu Raava and continue until the end of the world. 
Looks like there is one god in the story and that word obviously does not show. 
Vaatu did not pray for the first man on earth before the first humans arrived. At the time of the prophet.

Comment: Is this an opinion or do you have in universe support for this answer?

Answer (score 0):

dark avatar cycle has broken because if any avatar die in the avatar state the cycle will broke so the dark avatar has kill in the avatar state so vaatu will never return again

Answer (score -1):

i belive korra and raava have deafeted vaatu and unalq, but not forever. vaatu and unalq will probably be back for the next hermonic convergence in 10,000 that still leaves many questions though. i think the episode should have explained more for what has happened to unalq and vaatu.

Answer (score -1):

Ow man. I have a story. vaatu grows becouse of the bad that happens in the world. You can't see a spirit with his real form . But they change there forms. There is a difference between spirits and souls. Spirits dies and Souls didn't die. Spirits have their souls like humans have their souls. A spirit can die. They say the spirits are imortal. But that means the humans can't kill a spirit when they are in the spirit world. becouse we saw that the spirits dies when the humans go in the spirit world and kills the spirits. but the soul that can't die. In our religion it is that Satan will die on the end of the world and that the Angels will die on the end of the world. that means the devil and the Angels can't die until on the end of the world. Vaatu is alive and will go back in the boddy of korra. that is why Korra saw Vaatu when she was grazy.

Comment: That is a shabby answer. Punctuation, spelling, grammar. No good.